# Open a webpage in the default browser

Tags: vb.net, browser

I want my users to be able to click a button to open my company's webpage in the default browser when clicked.  How would I do this?

I'm using VB.net so all .net examples are acceptable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening default web browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562183/opening-default-web-browser)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As others have indicated, `Process.Start()` is the way to go here.  However, there are a few quirks.  It's worth your time to read this blog post:

> http://faithlife.codes/blog/2008/01/using_processstart_to_link_to/

In summary, some browsers cause it to throw an exception for no good reason, the function can block for a while on non-UI thread so you need to make sure it happens near the end of whatever other actions you might perform at the same time, and you might want to change the cursor appearance while waiting for the browser to open.

Answer (score 51):

This should work:

```
Dim webAddress As String = "http://www.example.com/"
Process.Start(webAddress)
```

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(webAddress)

Answer (score 11):

Here is a little sub that may just interest some people who need to specify the browser.
(but its not as good as a 12" pizza sub!) :P

```
Private Sub NavigateWebURL(ByVal URL As String, Optional browser As String = "default")

    If Not (browser = "default") Then
        Try
            '// try set browser if there was an error (browser not installed)
            Process.Start(browser, URL)
        Catch ex As Exception
            '// use default browser
            Process.Start(URL)
        End Try

    Else
        '// use default browser
        Process.Start(URL)

    End If

End Sub
```

---

Call: will open www.google.com in Firefox if it is installed on that PC.

```
NavigateWebURL("http://www.google.com", "Firefox") '// safari Firefox chrome etc
```

---

Call: will open www.google.com in default browser.

```
NavigateWebURL("http://www.google.com", "default")
```

OR

```
NavigateWebURL("http://www.google.com")
```

Comment: Upvoting for the lame pun

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx):

```
Dim url As String = “http://www.example.com“

Process.Start(url)
```

This should open whichever browser is set as default on the system.

Answer (score 2):

This worked perfectly for me. Since this is for personal use, I used Firefox as my browser.

```
 Dim url As String
    url = "http://www.google.com"
    Process.Start("Firefox", url)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim URL As String 
Dim browser As String = TextBox1.Text
URL = TextBox1.Text
Try
    If Not (browser = TextBox1.Text) Then
        Try
            Process.Start(browser, URL)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Process.Start(URL)
        End Try
    Else
        Process.Start(URL)
    End If

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("There's something wrong!")
End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.example.com")

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub URLOpen(Url As String)

    Dim OpenURL As New ProcessStartInfo With {
        .UseShellExecute = True,
        .FileName = "explorer.exe",
        .Arguments = Url
    }

    Process.Start(OpenURL)

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

or sometimes it's very easy just type
Process.Start("http://www.example.com/")

then change the http://www.example.com/")