# Launch Web URL in NON-default browser

Tags: c#, url, process, launch

I know that this:

```
Process.Start("http://www.somewebsite.com/");
```

launches a webpage in the users default browser. But, I am creating a useful little application, and now I need to be able to launch a URL in Chrome, Opera, Firefox, and Internet Explorer.

My default browser is Chrome, but how can I launch the URL in Opera or Firefox?
This is a personal application, and is only going to be used on my computer, so there is no need to think about how to get the installation directory of the browsers.

My Firefox browswer is here: `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe`
Do I need to do this by passing the URL as a command line parameter to `firefox.exe` when I use `Process.Start()`? And if that is what I need to do, can someone show me an example of how to do it?

Comment: This is exactly what you are looking for: Nice sub to use
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613239/open-a-webpage-in-the-default-browser/#15192260

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe", "http://www.somewebsite.com/");
```

**See also:**
[Firefox command line options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options)
[MSDN page for Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx)

Comment: I think you need to dispose the return value.

Answer (score 3):

I did that some time ago, just use:

```
string browser = "chrome.exe";
//string browser = "firefox.exe";
//...

Process myProcess = new Process();
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = browser;
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + url + "\"";
myProcess.Start();
```