# HyperlinkButton NavigateUri does not work in Safari

Tags: xaml, silverlight, safari

I use HyperLinkButton and add method in c# code for click for him.

Code method:

```
void btnViewURL_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
         if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(viewURL) == false
         && this.decisionViewModel.IsURLValid(viewURL))
         {
             System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(viewURL, UriKind.Absolute), "_blank");
         }
}
```

This code worked in ie but not in Safari.

After I try to use NavigateUrl property in xaml. I added binding, but this method does not work too in Safari. If I set plain text url (for example - "https://google.com" without binding so then Safari opened link.

```
<HyperlinkButton Margin="8,0,0,0" x:Name="linkStaticURL" 
    NavigateUri="{Binding viewURL}"
    TargetName="_blank">
                <TextBlock Text="Reader"</TextBlock>
</HyperlinkButton>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: what is the real URI you want to display ?

Comment: Where is viewURL defined? And is this really WPF? What is HyperlinkButton then?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Process.Start` to open the URL in your default browser:

```
void btnViewURL_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(viewURL) == false)
      && this.decisionViewModel.IsURLValid(viewURL))
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(viewURL);
    }
}
```

If you want to launch a specific web browser, you could pass its location to the same method as suggested here:

[Launch Web URL in NON-default browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148935/launch-web-url-in-non-default-browser)

And besides setting a `NavigateUri` you should also handle the `RequestNavigate` event:

[Example using Hyperlink in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238694/example-using-hyperlink-in-wpf)