# Specific page to open in webbrowser

Tags: vb.net

To open a specific page on vb.net we can use code

```
 Dim webAddress As String = "http://www.example.com/"
    Process.Start(webAddress)
```

Refference : [Open a webpage in default webbrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613239/open-a-webpage-in-the-default-browser)

But what if we wan't to open the page like `localhost/thing` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make sure you use http:// in front of your localhost url:

```
Dim webAddress As String = "http://localhost/thing"
Process.Start(webAddress)
```