# Error thrown trying launch a webpage from a button

Tags: vb.net, winforms, .net-core, .net-6.0

I created a button and a menu item in vb.net (.NET 6). I [found several answers here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6613260/692250) that say the process to launching a webpage from such an event can be launched with this code:

```
Dim webAddress As String = "http://www.example.com/"
Process.Start(webAddress)
```

However, trying launch the code, I'm given the error of "system cannot find the file specified".

Looking more into it, I know that .NET 6 is running a bit differently and changed the code to the following:

```
        Using link As New Process()
            link.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
            link.Start(New ProcessStartInfo("https://example.com"))
        End Using
```

But still to no avail, and I am given the same error. "System cannot find the file specified." I can run addresses via the regular Windows Run prompt... but the program still cannot launch.

Comment: Code works ok for me and opens in my default browser. What happens if you Start-Run->https://example.com ?

Answer (score 1):

Following Jimi's comment to my original question, I changed the Sub to the following:

```
Sub LaunchWebsite(strWebpageURL As String)

    Using Process.Start(New ProcessStartInfo(strWebpageURL) With {.UseShellExecute = True})
    End Using

End Sub
```

Using this, the webpage launched in my desktop's default browser with no problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
    Respone.Redirect("http://www.example.com/")
```

or use javascript in server side code

```
Dim url As String = "http://www.example.com"
Dim s As String = "window.open('" & url + "', 'popup_window', 'width=300,height=100,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes');"
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "script", s, True)
```

Above code open webpage in new popup window.

Regards
Aravind

Comment: You missed the `winforms` Tag (i.e., Desktop application, using Windows Forms)